# Probabilistic properties of Random.NextDouble

Tags: c#, .net, random

The *System.Random* class is a reasonably fast pseudo-random number generator, although it shouldn't be generally used for cryptography. However, is it at least a good statistically random number generator? I am interested in whether the method has these properties or not:

1. Able to generate *every* double in between 0 and 1 (excluding 1) from *any* seed (after a finite number of iterations, of course).
2. Generating each number has a probability proportional to the count of all possible numbers (1/4607182418800017408).
3. May generate subnormal numbers.
4. Probability of the generated number being in a specific interval is proportional to the length of the interval, down to the double resolution (e.g. being in [0,1) is 100%, [0,1/2) is 50%, [0,1/4) is 25 % etc. for all intervals).

I understand some of these are quite difficult restrictions, but the exact proportions may not be so numerically accurate.

Note that some of these points may be exclusive, mainly 2. and 4. (as double numbers are denser around 0, if 2. holds, the probability of being in [0,1/2) is larger than [1/2,1), like 999 in 1000).

Are there other random number generators that satisfy some of these points?

Comment: There is probably no practical PRNG at all which can be proved to fulfill all that (those are some very hard restrictions). And most of the time the default PRNGs are worse in regards to your list than PRNGs explicitly designed for doubles like [this one](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/SFMT/dSFMT-slide-e.pdf). But it's always about your task and to recognize what exactly you need. The current state of PRNGs reflect somehow what kind of tasks are common. It may be even hard to find something where those restrictions are critical (despite theoretical constructions).

Comment: Donald Knuth made sure you won't be disappointed.  Nobody argues with Donald.

Comment: @HansPassant That's very broad. The 1981 version, which might be still the core is obviously far worse than more modern PRNGs (compare test01 results). It's also an integer-based PRNG with all the problems in regards to double output. But everyone has to decide for himself, what kind of quality he needs.

Comment: I have updated the question to state that exact precise proportions are not needed. And as always, I'm just interested and not solving any particular problem.